# Missing symbol using newtxmath package

Tags: math-mode, symbols, newtxmath, missing, styles

I use the following setting but some math symbols missed e.g. +, (),...

> ```
> \usepackage{newtxtext} %different text font
> \usepackage{newtxmath} %different math font
> \let\openbox\undefined
> \let\Bbbk\relax
> \let\circledS\undefined
> \usepackage{eucal} 
> \usepackage{amsmath}
> \usepackage{latexsym}
> \usepackage{amsthm}
> \usepackage{mathrsfs}
> \usepackage{amsfonts}
> \usepackage{amssymb}
> \usepackage{mathtools}
> \usepackage{braket}
> \usepackage{feynmf}
> \usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
> \usepackage{secdot}
> \geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=3cm}
> \usepackage{lmodern}
> \usepackage[english]{babel}
> \usepackage{graphicx}
> \usepackage{caption}
> \captionsetup{margin=20pt,font=small,labelfont=bf}
> \usepackage{epsfig,labelfig}
> \usepackage{tipa}
> \usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
> \usepackage{float}
> \usepackage{booktabs}
> \usepackage{microtype}
> \usepackage{overpic}
> \usepackage{sectsty}
>
> \usepackage[
>   pdftitle={PDF},
>   pdfauthor={Author},
>   ocgcolorlinks,
>   linkcolor=linkred,
>   citecolor=linkred,
>   urlcolor=linkblue]
> {hyperref}
>
> \usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{hyperref}
> \usepackage{hyperref}
> \hypersetup{
>     colorlinks=true,
>     linkcolor=blue,
>     urlcolor=red,
>     linktoc=all,
>     citecolor=orange
>            }
>
> \usepackage{xcolor}
> \usepackage{cancel}
> \usepackage{slashed}
> %\usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
> \usepackage[tiny]{titlesec}
>   \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{12pt}{0pt}
>   \titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{6pt}{0pt}
> ```

What should I do now? Besides that, are there many things redundant in my code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why loading `lmodern` after `newtx...`? Also loading `hyperref` three times with different options will produce errors; don't load both `sectsty` and `titlesec`. Remove `epsfig`,`latexsym` and `amssymb`.

Comment: Thanks, I moved lmodern and it worked

Comment: in general only include packages that you use in the document loading unused packages makes this sort of clash very likely. It is highly unlikely that you are using `epsfig` for example (I wrote that as a legacy compatibility package in 1993 for documents that were writen for earlier versions of latex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Actually, I am using epsfig, here is the code of a figure I added, do you have better solution for it?
\begin{figure}[H]
%\ShowGrid
\leavevmode \SetLabels
\L(.465*.34) $\alpha$\\%
\L(.49*.345) $\beta$\\
\endSetLabels
\begin{center}
\AffixLabels{\centerline{\epsfig{file =fig.geoquad.pdf,width=6cm,angle=0}}}
\vspace{-24pt}
\end{center}
\caption{......} \label{fig:quadri}
\end{figure}

Comment: please stop using it, it was just designed to ease people from latex2.09 to latex2e last century, why are you using it now rather than the standard `\includegraphics` ?

Comment: `\epsfig{file =fig.geoquad.pdf,width=6cm,angle=0}}}` is just a wrapper giving historic syntax then calls the standard `\includegraphics[width=6cm,angle=0]{fig.geoquad.pdf}`

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!